# Android - Horizontal progress bar with dots

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I have a project that the user answers questions in a form.
I need to implement a horizontal progress bar (not a dialog), with dots instead the normal bar.

When the user answers a question, the dot of that specific question changes the color.
This is possible? I'm using API 16 (target) and API 7 (minimum) with Sherlock ActionBar

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37741873/7104450

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a large number of questions, it might be sufficient if you just use multiple ImageViews to represent the dots. Example of XML:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/dotsL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot1"
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_white" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot2"
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dot1"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_white" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot3"
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dot2"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_white" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot4"
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dot3"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_white" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot5"
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dot4"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_white" >
        </ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

In java:

```
    mDots = new ImageView[5];
    mDots[0] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dot1);
    mDots[1] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dot2);
    mDots[2] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dot3);
    mDots[3] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dot4);
    mDots[4] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dot5);
```

And when user answers a question, just :

```
mDots[questionNumber].setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circle_green));
```

Note: This approach requires that you have according drawables.

Comment: I think this would work if I already know the amount of question that the user will answer, but the number of questions is not in my control, the user creates the form in a website, and he may create a form with 10 question or 100. I can't do a static number of dots in the xml, I have to instance they programmatically with a N factor

Comment: You are right in that case, you have to instantiate ImageViews programatically, which certainly is possible. Maybe not the cleanest way of solving this problem, but it should work.

Answer (score 2):

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/image_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
```

Adding pictures dynamically and hiding them (based on total number of questions), I also put the layout_weight equal to 1 as you can see, so each "dot" has the same size:

```
ImageView[] images = new ImageView[totQuestions];
LinearLayout imageLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.image_layout);  
ImageView image;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
for(int i = 0; i < totQuestions; i++){
    image = new ImageView(this);
    layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
    image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    image.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circle_green));
    image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    images[i] = image;
    imageLayout.addView(image);
}
```

Showing pictures after each answer:

```
imageLayout.getChildAt(questionNr).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //starting at 0
```

I just improved what **slezadav** suggested.

Comment: I'll test this and tomorrow I post a feedback, tkz!

Comment: I haven't tested this though, but I'm pretty sure it works. Could be some minor issue to this.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a ProgressBar widget included with the Android framework. This works in all types of layouts and is not restricted to dialogs.  Using that and specifying the android:progressDrawable or android:indeterminateDrawable property with your own dots drawable would be the easiest solution.  See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) for details.