# Intro Screens with Indicator Dots - Displays only first time - Android

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

Admittedly, I am Android newbie dev. I would like to know the best approach/solution to showing intro screens for an app, and ONLY at first time use. Similar to Google Drive and several other apps that show the intro screens when you open first time. It has dots at the button to show the screen number you are in. You can swipe to left or right. After you swipe of the last screen, you will enter into the app home screen.

Link to any examples that have screenshots would be good as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if android app is the first time used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636141/determine-if-android-app-is-the-first-time-used)

Comment: Well, this might answer the 2nd part. But 1st part?

Comment: Check out Swipe Views:
http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/swipe-views.html
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: We need to add a the dots (view/page indicator ) at the bottom separately?

Comment: Yes, but there is help for that as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288754/android-horizontal-progress-bar-with-dots

Answer (score 0):

You launch into the intro screen activity.  The first thing it does is check a shared preference.  If it exists, you skip the intro and launch the main activity.  If it doesn't, you display the first intro screen.  When you detect a swipe you switch to the proper new fragment.  If its the last screen, you launch the main activity.

Comment: That answers the 2nd question. But how do you display swipable screens? Is it a separate library / view?

Comment: Start with a ViewPager.  You will have to write some code yourself around that, although if you look you might find a 3rd party library.