# Android - Add three dots animation on Progress Dialog

Tags: java, android, animation, mobile

I'm working on a progress dialog that will popup when the button clicked.

I already got the 3 dots animation (using JumpingBeans) .

But now, I want to add it to the title of the Android Progress Dialog, and i think it's impossible, isn't it? Or how to attach the textview (moving dots) to the Progress dialog?

The three dots button isn't animated, what's the best way to make this custom progress dialog?

I was trying to create a DialogFragment with ProgressBar and TextView in it, but when I called the setMax and setProgress, it always got a NPE error (Null Pointer Exception).

Is there any simpler way or better way to handle this custom dialog fragment with dots animation?

Here's the picture (I want to make the dots moving)

[image]

Comment: refer this examples : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37741872/how-to-make-custom-dotted-progress-bar-in-android  Or  https://github.com/d-max/spots-dialog

Comment: hi @DixitPatel, thanks for stopping by, I already tried the spots-dialog, but it's not what i wanted, the objective is to make the three dots on the pic above move

Comment: I should request the dialog feature NO_TITLE, and setCustomView() onto the dialog, the custom view can have the design you want, so you can put the textViewTitle with the dots view animated next to it.PD: you can do this for dialog and dialogFragment

Comment: @marcosE. seems legit, i will give it a try and will inform you for the update

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved for it by updating the message on a separate thread.

Seems like this should work for title as well :

**Main Activity:**

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    public final static long RUN_TIME = 30000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        gotoMain();
    }

    private void gotoMain() {

        final String messagePrefix = "Loading ";
        final ProgressDialog startupProgressDialog =
                ProgressDialogUtil.createProgressDialog(
                        SplashActivity.this,

                        // space added on init so text doesn't shift when adding chars for first time
                        messagePrefix + "      "
                );

        startupProgressDialog.setTitle(null);
        startupProgressDialog.show();

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ProgressDialogUtil
                        .runAnimatedLoadingDots(
                                SplashActivity.this,
                                messagePrefix,
                                startupProgressDialog);
            }
        };
        thread.start();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                startupProgressDialog.dismiss();

                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainBottomNavActivity.class);
                SplashActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                SplashActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, RUN_TIME);
    }

}
```

**ProgressDialogUtil.java**

```
public class ProgressDialogUtil {

    public static ProgressDialog createProgressDialog(Context context, String message) {
        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.DialogTheme1);
        dialog.setTitle("App Initialization");
        dialog.setMessage(message);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        return dialog;
    }

    public static void runAnimatedLoadingDots(Activity activity, String messagePrefix, final ProgressDialog progressDialog) {

        int dotsCount = 0;
        while (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {

            dotsCount++;
            dotsCount = dotsCount % 5; // looks good w/4 dots

            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException iEx) {}

            final StringBuffer updateValue = new StringBuffer(messagePrefix);
            for (int i = 0; i < dotsCount; i++) {
                updateValue.append('.');
            }

            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressDialog.setMessage(updateValue.toString());
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```