# Create activity indicator like shape

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, shapes

I want to create a shape in android using xml like this.

[image]

I managed to create the inner white circle and below is my code for that but how can i make outer activity indicator like circle. I also would to like to animate the outer circle but that's not a priority for now but if someone can help me that as well, that would be great.

```
<item android:height="63dp" android:width="63dp" android:gravity="center">
    <shape
        android:shape="oval">

        <solid
            android:color="@color/white"/>
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#000000"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: Might not be the solution you need but go for vector images.... they are in xml format and light weight.
you can turn this jpeg/png into vector online..

Comment: You can also create this view as custom view on canvas, it will allow you to manage animations as you want, but this way is more complicated of course

Comment: you can create a custom view to handle refer this link for some reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37741872/how-to-make-custom-dotted-progress-bar-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Create your own canvas view. Look at this library for example https://github.com/dinuscxj/CircleProgressBar/blob/master/circleprogressbar/src/main/java/com/dinuscxj/progressbar/CircleProgressBar.java

To draw lines use next method

```
private void drawLineProgress(Canvas canvas) {
    float unitDegrees = (float) (2.0f * Math.PI / mLineCount);
    float outerCircleRadius = mRadius;
    float interCircleRadius = mRadius - mLineWidth;

    int progressLineCount = (int) ((float) getProgress() / (float) getMax() * mLineCount);

    for (int i = 0; i < mLineCount; i++) {
        float rotateDegrees = i * unitDegrees;

        float startX = mCenterX + (float) Math.sin(rotateDegrees) * interCircleRadius;
        float startY = mCenterX - (float) Math.cos(rotateDegrees) * interCircleRadius;

        float stopX = mCenterX + (float) Math.sin(rotateDegrees) * outerCircleRadius;
        float stopY = mCenterX - (float) Math.cos(rotateDegrees) * outerCircleRadius;

        if (i < progressLineCount) {
            canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, mProgressPaint);
        } else {
            canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, mProgressBackgroundPaint);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the referred library. Exactly, extend https://github.com/natasam/DemoProgressViewsLibApp/blob/master/progressviewslib/src/main/java/com/natasa/progressviews/CircleSegmentBar.java draw a solid filled circle inside and i think that should give you the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer use XML, I think you can achive your goal by `animation-list`. But I suggest you implement you own custom `View`, which draws all you need in `Canvas`. It will be flexible in case you need to change something.

Good luck!